# Adaptive menu on site

Tags: css

I need a menu that is located fixed at the bottom of the page

I can't do it right. Can someone help with the implementation and adaptivity

I tried to make it, but I can't make the connection between the logo and the menu items

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
  <a href="/"><img class="header__logo" src="/assets/icons/logo.png"></a>
</header>

<div class="navbar">

  <a href="/" class="navbar__logo">
    <img src="/assets/icons/logo.png">
    <img class="navbar__icon" src="/assets/icons/navbar.svg" alt="navbar">
  </a>

  <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="/" class="navbar__link navbar__link-selected">Связаться</a>
    <a href="/vacancies" class="navbar__link">Вакансии</a>
    <a href="/contacts" class="navbar__link">Контакты</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.navbar {
  z-index: 10000;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  // mix-blend-mode: normal;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;

  * {
    z-index: 2000;
  }
}

.navbar__logo {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(68, 68, 74, 1);
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar__logo img {
  z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar__icon {
  z-index: 100 !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar__logo img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.navbar__container {
  background-color: rgba(68, 68, 74, 1);
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.navbar__link {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 14px 24px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #6b6b6b;
  }
}

.navbar__link-selected {
  background-color: #27272b;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #27272b;
  }
}
```

I managed to create something similar. But the result still does not suit me, as it is difficult to adapt it to the mobile version.

Comment: Show your attempts please.

Comment: i edit post, you can now see code

Answer (score 0):

Below changes in your existing code can fix the issue for fixing a menu at the bottom of the link

HTML

```
   <header class="header">
   <a href="/" class="header_logo"
   <img src= "/assets/icons/logo.png" alt="Logo">
   </a>
   </header>
   <div class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="/" class="navbar__link navbar__link selected">
        Связаться</a>
     <a href="/vacancies" class="navbar__link">Вакансии</a>
     <a href="/contacts" class="navbar__link">Контакты</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    $navbar-height: 60px;
    .header {
    display: none; // Hide the header on mobile
    }

    .navbar {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     height: $navbar-height;
     background-color: rgba(68, 68, 74, 1);
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-around;
     align-items: center;
     }

      .navbar__container {
       display: flex;
       align-items: center;
       gap: 20px;
      }

     .navbar__link {
      font-size: 18px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      }

      .navbar__link-selected {
       background-color: #27272b;
       }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .header {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
     }

    .navbar {
    display: none; // Hide the navbar on desktop
    }
   }`
```